# How the Bytecode get stored in method area and gets executed in jvm

Tags: memory-management, jvm, runtime

I have read from some articles that When jvm starts ,it loads the bytecode in memory and  bytecode will be classified in method area as type information,constant pool,field and method information,method table,class variables. I am trying to understand how the flow of execution happens.

1. Will the bytecode gets executed line by line? if so the line by line bytecode will be stored where?
2. How method area components(information,constant pool,field and method information,method table,class variables) helps to execute a class
3. Where will be method code(some logic in function) will be stored to be performed?

   Can anyone help to get some knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things you ask are implementation dependant, so they could be implemented in a slightly different way depending on the java vm you choose (Oracle or others).

1. Yes, if you only have one thread. When the `.class` file is loaded, all [the information contained](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) that you mentioned are stored in different data structures. Usually all the information related to a single method will be contained in a method metadata struct and that structure will contain a specific field with an array/buffer of bytes with all the method's bytecode (loaded from the `method_info` `Code` attribute in the `.class`).
2. More than "help", they are needed because that information is usually referred to/used in the bytecode. The constant pool is a prime example of this, decompiling your `.class` with `javap` you'll notice reference to the content of the pool.
3. Same as **1**, the "logic" is expressed with bytecodes, that are the machine instruction of the java virtual machine. Your code is compiled to bytecode and then stored for each method, this and other data is used to produce a `.class`.

Comment: thanks for the reply... Will all the byte codes will be stored in constant pool?

Comment: No, the constant pool (1 for each class, used by all the methods) only contains constants strings and stringified class references. The byte codes are stored with other the method data in a different structture (likely a c struct if your vm is written in c/c++).

Comment: Thank you so much for the information... In the below example Can you please say which will be stored in the constant pool and method data . Also Can you please explain What is Symbolic reference in the below code,i have read that in resolution phase the symbolic reference are replaced by actual memory in the method area .. 
public class JVM